# Using a tie clip microfoon with amp

Tags: microphone, mixer

(an audio noob here, please explain in detail, I also want to learn:) )

I have a tie clip microphone (excuse me if that it is not the proper word for it, I mean a mic such as [here](https://www.coolblue.nl/product/732289/rode-smartlav.html)).

I have a PDM-X601-6 mixer and a PV240BT amp (both from power dynamics).

I want to plug in the tie clip microphone to the mixer (which is plugged into the amp). I want to do this wired, instead of with a wireless bodypack.

However I am not sure how to do this? What do I have to buy additionally to make this work?

Comment: It can be called a tie mic, that's perfectly understandable. In 'pro speak' it's called a lav mic \[short for [lavalier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavalier_microphone)\]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a Røde SC3 adapter to go from TRRS connector (laptop or mobile phone combo headset 1/8" plug) to TRS (laptop or mobile separate microphone input), then a Røde VXLR+ or VXLR Pro adapter to convert the +48V of phantom power on XLR that your mixer provides to +4V of "plugin power" required by the microphone.

Either product has, of course, also alternatives from other manufacturers.

Comment: Ah, OK, so Røde anticipated this, and made it very slightly cheaper than buying a new mic ;)) Hats off to them for at least making it possible.

Comment: tbh, I occasionally have the opposite problem - DPA 4060 mic, phantom-powered, which I very occasionally would want to connect to a consumer DSLR. So far, I've just recorded via a separate route to DAW & synced it up later to the onboard camera mic/clapper.

Comment: (excuse me for the late response, forgot that I asked the question here as well)
Thank for the answer, the Røde VXLR+ is exactly what I searched for. I believe that will work in this case:)